# Picture tag shows broken image when matched source tag results in 403 and XML response (from S3)

Tags: html, image, amazon-s3

We're hosting images on Amazon's S3. If an image doesn't exist, it returns a `403` and an XML response. The picture tag still matches the `media` query on the `source` tag and tries to show it, resulting in a broken image.

How can i make the picture tag use the fallback `img` tag when a `403` (with a response body) is returned?

```
<picture>

    <!-- This matches but returns a 403. -->
    <source srcSet="amazon-s3-url/image-retina" media="(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),(min-resolution: 192dpi)">
    <img src="amazon-s3-url/non-retina />
</picture>
```

Comment: did you ever find a workaround? I haven't been able to find anything yet. Might have to write some javascript.

Comment: @Grim yes, it's been a long time but i believe we added an `onerror` handler and in there we check what the `currentSrc` is, and if it matches the non-default image, we set it to the default one

Comment: ill use the onerror attribute if we decide to use the picture tag